# Why are data in my package "serialized" and not being read in the most-recent version of R?

Tags: r, package

I've written a small package that is useful for sharing functions and example data with colleagues, and I recently added a few more data files to it. The computer I was using when I did that was running R version 4.0.0. However, when I tried to use `devtools` to install that package from github onto a computer running R version 4.0.2, I get the following message:

`NB: this package now depends on R (>= 3.5.0)`

`WARNING: Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in  serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.  File(s) containing such objects:  'LaurasHelpers/data/Candidates.RData'`

I don't know what it means that my data are serialized. I haven't changed how I save things. Here's how I saved a data.frame called "MyData" to the "data" folder of my package:

```
 save(MyData, "MyData.RData")
```

After seeing the initial answer to my post, I then tried

```
 save(MyData, "MyData.RData", version = 2)
```

Next, I updated everything:

```
 devtools::document()
 devtools::build()
```

From git bash, I pushed my changes to my github repo. Then, back in RStudio, I did:

```
 remove.packages("LaurasHelpers")
 devtools::install_github(repo = "shirewoman2/LaurasHelpers")
```

But when I load my package, I still can't load certain data files into my workspace using `data(MyData)`.

Two questions:

1. Why are data files that I've saved using R 4.0.0 not able to be loaded in R 4.0.2? Both of those are more recent than R 3.5.0.
2. How do I avoid this problem so that anyone who loads my package can open my pretty simple data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning doesn't mean/isn't telling you that you can't load files saved in 4.0.0 in 4.0.2. Rather, it's warning you that others using R < 3.5.0 won't be able to load your saved files.

When you save your data, use

```
save(MyObject, file = "MyObject.RData", version = 2)
```

to maintain back-compatibility and avoid the warning.

From the [R 3.x news file](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.3.html), under version 3.6.0:

> Serialization format version 3 becomes the default for serialization and saving of the workspace (save(), serialize(), saveRDS(), compiler::cmpfile()). Serialized data in format 3 cannot be read by versions of R prior to version 3.5.0. Serialization format version 2 is still supported and can be selected by version = 2 in the save/serialization functions. The default can be changed back for the whole R session by setting environment variables R_DEFAULT_SAVE_VERSION and R_DEFAULT_SERIALIZE_VERSION to 2. For maximal back-compatibility, files ‘vignette.rds’ and ‘partial.rdb’ generated by R CMD build are in serialization format version 2, and resave by default produces files in serialization format version 2 (unless the original is already in format version 3).

Comment: Odd... That's not working for me. I can't even load those objects on the computer I wrote the package on now. I mean, I can navigate to where they're stored and use `load(...` to load them, but I can't load them using `data(...`. I've saved them using the "version 2" option, but that didn't work.

Comment: In data(Candidates) : data set "Candidates" not found

Comment: don't know.  Probably not related to serialization. Probably something about package structure/installation/etc., maybe not solvable without a [mcve] ...

Comment: Ok, I tried my best to come up with an example, but I guess it's more a more-thorough description of what I did. Kinda hard to have someone create a whole new package as an example.

Comment: Figured out that I had TWO problems! I had an error with version control in git *and* I had the problem with not saving using "version 2". Once I found my git mistake, the "verion 2" did the trick for saving my data! Thanks!